# Disable JAX-RS in WebSphere

Tags: java, websphere, jax-rs, websphere-8

If i disable built in JAX-RS via JVM property 
com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.DisableIBMJAXRSEngine=true in IBM Websphere. Does it disable other functionality like EJB or JCDI integration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This flag only disables EJB integration and CDI from JAX-RS components. They will still be working for example in servlets or EJBs.

You can find more details in [Disabling the JAX-RS runtime environment](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.iseries.doc/ae/twbs_jaxrs_disable_runtime.html?lang=en)